# Does the value function of a quadratic program stay convex when adding constraints?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

I am interested in the value function of a quadratic program of the form
$$
v(y)=\min_x \frac{1}{2} x^\top Q(y) x,
$$
subject to a linear equality constraint
$$
E(y)x=d(y),
$$
and a linear inequality constraint
$$
A x \preceq b,
$$
where $\preceq$ denotes component-wise inequalities.

Notice that $Q$, $E$ and $d$ all depend on a parameter $y\in{\Bbb R}^m_{\geq 0}$. $Q(y)$ is positive definite for all $y$. Importantly, $A$ and $b$ do not depend on $y$.

For the particular problem I am interested in, I know $Q$, $E$, $d$, $A$ and $b$ but they are a bit complicated and I'm hoping that their specific structure is not important here.

**I would like to show that $v$ is convex.** Given my specific problem, I know that $v$ is convex if we remove the inequality constraint $A x \preceq b$. In that case the problem is simple and I can solve for $v$.

My question is: if $v$ is convex without the inequality constraint, does $v$ remain convex when we add the inequality constraint? Recall that this inequality constraint does not depend on $y$.

Notes:

1. If that helps, in my specific problem $Q$ and $E$ are homogenous in the sense that $Q(\lambda y)=\lambda Q(y)$ and $E(\lambda y)=\lambda E(y)$ for any $\lambda\in{\Bbb R}$, and $d(y)=y-c$ where $c\in{\Bbb R}^m_{\geq 0}$. $E$ is also linear.
2. I tried to compute $v$ using the dual approach but this seems intractable.
3. I have looked at a few special cases and cannot find a counterexample.

Comment: What does mean $Ax\preceq b$? Do you mean just inequalities?

Comment: Yes, component-wise inequality. I've followed the notation that wikipedia uses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming

Comment: Cross-posted: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/10748/does-the-value-function-of-a-quadratic-program-stay-convex-when-adding-constrain

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451487/does-the-value-function-of-a-quadratic-program-stay-convex-when-adding-constrain/ for an answer to this question by @fedja. It turns out that $v$ is not convex in general, but there are some restrictions we can impose on $Q$, $E$, $d$, $A$ and $b$ such that it is.